# Where can I find good surveys on Symplectic and Contact geometry

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, contact-geometry

Are there any good survey articles in symplectic and contact geometry, which focus on the "big picture", i.e how this discipline fits into the mathematical world ?

In the symplectic case : I am looking for surveys which explain the differences between the group of symplectic diffeomorphisms (and its Hamiltonian subgroup) and the group of volume preserving diffeomorphisms, through rigidity considerations. In addition, I would like to understand the motivation behind the use of generating functions to treat fixed points problems.

In the contact case : I would like to read about the link between contact geometry and simple Lie algebras, the physical motivation between the Reeb flow, and the motivation behind the concept of prequantization spaces. In addition, I would like to understand the motivation behind the study of fixed points up to Reeb flow: studying fixed points in odd-dimensional spaces is apparently not interesting (why ?).